# insert JSON into a hashmap

Tags: json, ruby

I am facing some issue to insert a json file into a hashmap.

```
dest = { ... extra = { 'gen'.to_sym => data,  #it works
                       'det'.to_sym => JSON.parse(myjson) }

myjson is something like { aaa = 2, bbb=3.... }
```

When I am doing the

```
'det'.to_sym => JSON.parse(myjson)
```

ruby complains by raising the issue : no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Any idea how to insert a JSON inside a hashmap easily ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your myjson variable is already a hash?  Try doing puts myjson.class.name to see what it is...

Comment: Examples are much better when they are complete so that readers can demonstrate how they propose computing the desired return value.

Comment: Yes can you print out the value of my_json

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to parse something that is not json just turn the hash into json if you want json as your value

```
dest = { ... extra = { 'gen'.to_sym => data,  #it works
                       'det'.to_sym => JSON.parse(myjson.to_json) }
```

Comment: Sorry. Remove the .to_json it's à mistake.

Comment: Ok I'm a little confused are you trying to add json to your hash, or are you trying to add a hash that you transformed from json to your hash?

Comment: I am trying to add a json to my hash

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing called `hashmap` in ruby.
2. The problem has nothing to do with inserting into hash.

You are messing the hash and json up. You don’t need to parse anything in that stage, and trying to parse a valid hash produces the error. Instead of

```
'det'.to_sym => JSON.parse(myjson)
```

just do:

```
'det'.to_sym => myjson
```